# How does a standalone object get affected when the actual object is deleted from realm?

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

Lets say I have a standalone object called, standAloneObject, which was created from the original object (called originalObject) by using the method initWithValue. If I delete originalObject from realm, does it invalidate standAloneObject? If not, can I re-add the object by using createOrUpdateInRealm:withValues:?

If its of any importance, this is all done on the main thread.

EDIT:

```
MyRLMObject *standAloneObject = [[MyRLMObject alloc] initWithValue:persistedObject];
RLMRealm *defaultRealm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
[defaultRealm beginWriteTransaction];
[defaultRealm deleteObject: persistedObject];
[defaultRealm commitWriteTransaction];

[defaultRealm beginWriteTransaction];
[defaultRealm addOrUpdateObject:standAloneObject];
[defaultRealm commitWriteTransaction];
```

This is a very simplified version of what I am trying to do, but it effectively captures the essence of what I am trying to do.

Comment: There are some compile errors in your code, so I fixed. If the above code is correct, I cannot reproduce any error. If you still have the error, please send  your reproducible project to help@realm.io for an investigation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I delete originalObject from realm, does it invalidate standAloneObject?

No. The standalone object that was created by `initWithValue:` is isolated from Realm. It's just an object. (So standalone object pass across threads.)

> If not, can I re-add the object by using createOrUpdateInRealm:withValues:?

Yes. You can re-add the standalone object with `createOrUpdateInRealm:withValues:`

Comment: Thats exactly what I thought, however I am getting an exception thrown from realm when I try this. The exception is "RLMException - Adding a deleted or invalidated object to a Realm is not permitted"

What are some things I can do on my end to figure out what is causing this problem? I also noticed in debugger, when I deleted originalObject, I could no longer print description the standAloneObject.

Comment: @JasperChan Could you share your code by updating your question?

Comment: Done as requested. Thanks for your help! :)